# Java Arrayindexoutofboundexception

Tags: java, arrays

```
try {
    rs = stmt.executeQuery("select firstname, middlename, lastname from users where  username = '" + var_1 + "'");
    if (rs == null || (!rs.next())) {
        record = var_1;
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("C:/workspace/table_export.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] tokens = line.split("\\s+");
            if (tokens[0].equals(record)) {
                int size = tokens.length;
                for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
                    fw.append(tokens[i]);
                    fw.append(',');
                }
                fw.append('\n');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hi all,

Am trying to query a database using a filter value retrieved from text file.

If the result set returns empty, i am searching for that filter value in the same text file and copying the whole line that contained the values to an array by splitting space.

Then i write the array to a csv file.

My text file has values like this

```
yzr200123 xxxx yyyy  
dd4534554 xydy frde

var_1=yzr200123, dd4534554
```

Note: This var_1 value does not exist in db, so i have to search for the value in text file and write the whole line to csv..

output.csv

```
yzr200123,xxxx,yyyy

dd4534554,xydy,frde
```

As one could see its writing to the csv file but i am getting the following exception,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
at simplejdbc.SimpleJDBC.getstaffid(SimpleJDBC.java:119)
at simplejdbc.SimpleJDBC.main(SimpleJDBC.java:64)
```

Is there a way we can avoid this exception by tuning the code.
Any inputs would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Side note :use  `while (rs==null || (!rs.next()) )` instead of if `(rs==null || (!rs.next()) )`

Comment: could you please indent your code ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for(int i=0;i<=size;i++)
```

Is wrong. Since array indexes start from `0`, you have to loop until `i<size`.

```
for(int i=0;i < size;i++) {
    fw.append(tokens[i]);
    fw.append(',');
}
```

Let's say that the array length is `4`. Indexes are 0-based, so available indexes will be `0, 1, 2, 3`. With your loop, you are trying to access indexes `0, 1, 2, 3, 4`. The 5th element (which has index `4`) doesn't exist, so it will throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`